# How can i access jsp session in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to access some common login data like user id, name, etc in JavaScript. I can add the data to jsp session. But is there a way to access it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

No. Sessions are serverside concept. If you need that info on clientside, have your serverside code pass it along explicitly:

```
<script>
  var userID = <% out.print(userID); %>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `request` Object to get the parameter you need like this,

```
`request.getSession().getAttribute("username)`.
```

Or use `EL` instead. And don't forget to add

```
`<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>`
```

on your jsp file.

`EL` will pick the parameter's value by `action scope`.
Cause `requestScope < sessionScope`, so if there's a parameter named `'username'` in `requestScope` and `sessionScope`, it will search and pick the value in `requestScope` first, then `sessionScope`, then...
Just like the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* test in my own jsp file with isELIgnored="false"
          <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
          <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
        */
        <% request.getSession().setAttribute("author", "Vincent"); %>
        var author = "<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("author") %>";
        alert(author);
        author = "${sessionScope.author}";
        alert(author);
</script>
```